# Javascript return undefined of recursive function with Date()

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem with a recursive javascript function - The return value is undefined:

```
function get_next_weekday(timesec) {

    var nextdaytogo = timesec;
    var nextday;
    var hour = timesec.getHours();
    initstunden = 13 - hour;
    initminuten = 59 - timesec.getMinutes();
    var holidays = [
        new Date(2016, 11, 25).toDateString(), new Date(2016, 11, 26).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 00, 01).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 00, 06).toDateString(), 
        new Date(2017, 03, 14).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 03, 17).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 04, 01).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 04, 25).toDateString(), 
        new Date(2017, 05, 05).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 05, 15).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 09, 03).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 10, 01).toDateString(), 
        new Date(2017, 11, 25).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 11, 26).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 00, 01).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 00, 06).toDateString(), 
        new Date(2018, 02, 30).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 03, 02).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 04, 01).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 04, 10).toDateString(), 
        new Date(2018, 04, 21).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 04, 31).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 09, 03).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 10, 01).toDateString(), 
        new Date(2018, 11, 25).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 11, 26).toDateString()
    ];


    if ( $.inArray(timesec.toDateString(), holidays) > -1 || timesec.getDay() == 0 || timesec.getDay() == 6) {
        console.log("if() Statement")
        //Holiday
        if ( $.inArray(timesec.toDateString(), holidays) > -1){
            console.log("Holiday Func." + timesec);
            var nextday = new Date(timesec.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            var next = get_next_weekday(nextday);

        }
        //Sunday
        else if (timesec.getDay() == 0){
            console.log("Sunday Func." + timesec);
            var nextday = new Date(timesec.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            var next = get_next_weekday(nextday);

        }
        //Saturday
        else if (timesec.getDay() == 6){
            console.log("Saturday Func." + timesec);
            var nextday = new Date(timesec.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            var next = get_next_weekday(nextday);

        }
        else console.log("Und. Func.");


    }
    else{
        console.log("else Statement - Value: " + next);
        return timesec;
    }
}

var daydeliver = get_next_weekday(aktuell);
console.log("Func. - Return: " + daydeliver);
```

And this is the log:

1. if() Statement  SaturdayFunc.Sat Dec 23 2017 11:11:53 GMT+0100 if()
   Statement  Sunday Func.Sun Dec 24 2017 11:11:53 GMT+0100 if()
   Statement  Holiday Func.Mon Dec 25 2017 11:11:53 GMT+0100 if()
   Statement  Holiday Func.Tue Dec 26 2017 11:11:53 GMT+0100 else
   Statement - Value: undefined  Func. - Return: undefined

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: your `next` is undefined because you set next variable under function (local scope). everytime your function return recursive (holiday in this case) it set local `next` variable. then finaly (get the correct date), which is no `next` variable defined--undefined--...sorry mouthfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because you declare var in local scope + you return nothing when recursive fn triggered. I suppose you want `next` to hold previous date from recursive fn. Please review this one:

```js
//next will return undefined if no recursive function called
var next;
function get_next_weekday(timesec) {

    var nextdaytogo = timesec;
    var nextday;
    var hour = timesec.getHours();
    initstunden = 13 - hour;
    initminuten = 59 - timesec.getMinutes();
    var holidays = [
        new Date(2016, 11, 25).toDateString(), new Date(2016, 11, 26).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 00, 01).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 00, 06).toDateString(), 
        new Date(2017, 03, 14).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 03, 17).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 04, 01).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 04, 25).toDateString(), 
        new Date(2017, 05, 05).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 05, 15).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 09, 03).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 10, 01).toDateString(), 
        new Date(2017, 11, 25).toDateString(), new Date(2017, 11, 26).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 00, 01).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 00, 06).toDateString(), 
        new Date(2018, 02, 30).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 03, 02).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 04, 01).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 04, 10).toDateString(), 
        new Date(2018, 04, 21).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 04, 31).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 09, 03).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 10, 01).toDateString(), 
        new Date(2018, 11, 25).toDateString(), new Date(2018, 11, 26).toDateString()
    ];


    if ( $.inArray(timesec.toDateString(), holidays) > -1 || timesec.getDay() == 0 || timesec.getDay() == 6) {
        console.log("if() Statement")
        //Holiday
        if ( $.inArray(timesec.toDateString(), holidays) > -1){
            console.log("Holiday Func." + timesec);
            let nextday = new Date(timesec.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
             next = timesec;
             return get_next_weekday(nextday);

        }
        //Sunday
        else if (timesec.getDay() == 0){
            console.log("Sunday Func." + timesec);
            let nextday = new Date(timesec.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            next = timesec;
          return get_next_weekday(nextday);

        }
        //Saturday
        else if (timesec.getDay() == 6){
            console.log("Saturday Func." + timesec);
            let nextday = new Date(timesec.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            next = timesec;
          return get_next_weekday(nextday);

        }
        else {console.log("Und. Func.");
            next = "Und. Func.";return;
            }
    }
    else{
        console.log("else Statement - Value: " + next);
        return timesec;
    }    
}

var daydeliver = get_next_weekday(new Date(2016, 11, 11));
console.log("Func. - Return: " + daydeliver);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```